# IIS Express Debugging No Longer Working

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm using IIS Express with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 x64 for a WebAPI 2 application (all en-US here). This worked just fine roughly a month ago, but now I'm getting errors when attempting to debug the application.

If I do not run VS as admin (again, didn't need to do this before), I get:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\~AspAccessCheck_c00414062044.tmp' is denied.
```

A second error occurs after this, or it will be the first error if I run VS as Administrator:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Culture is not supported.
```

If I run the same WebAPI application from WebMatrix 3, it runs without errors (with or without running 'as Admin').

Project IIS config settings:

```
<UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
<IISExpressSSLPort>46435</IISExpressSSLPort>
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
<IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>false</IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>
```

I also have the application running on http://localhost:46436.

What I also find really strange is that the project properties show "IIS Express" and to use a URL of http://localhost:46436/, but in the project file I'm seeing:

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>46435</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:46436</IISUrl>
```

That may explain my access denied. Regardless if I unset, save, and re-set to use IIS Express (storing it for all users), the `<UseIIS>` property is set back to true.

EDIT: It looks like "Use IIS" is normal. I created a new WebAPI 2 project as a test. It ran fine under IIS Express OOTB.

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions on C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\~AspAccessCheck_c00414062044.tmp? Are they different from the other files in the folder?

Comment: That file is used to check to see if the user running the process has rights. But regardless, it works as the same user under a new WebAPI 2 project running VS w/o admin.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue.  Ended up having to right click the folder in question and add access for the IIS_IUSR account.

If this isn't causing critical errors, you can also disable break mode for this sort of issue via **Debug -> Options -> Debugging** and check **Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)**

Comment: You did better than me, it cost me 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I updated all of the packages via the 'Manage NuGet Packages' console, and it started working.